# SBCL Lisp imputes type to inner loop at runtime. How do I override this?

Tags: algorithm, common-lisp, sbcl

I implemented a solution to a Project Euler problem using an approach loosely based on the meet-in-the-middle algorithm for the knapsack problem. However, SBCL--and only SBCL--won't compile my solution.

The relevant chunk of code is:

```
(loop with upper-half = <list in descending order>
      and lower-half = <list in ascending order>
      for i in lower-half maximize (loop for j on upper-half
                                         for prod = (* (car j) i)
                                         when (> upper-limit prod)
                                          return (prog1 prod (setf upper-half j))))
```

The numbers on `upper-half` and `lower-half` are such that the inner loop never reaches the end of `upper-half` and the inner loop never returns `Nil`.

While this does run on Lispworks, SBCL emits the following error:

```
  warning:
    Constant NIL conflicts with its asserted type REAL.
    See also:
      SBCL Manual, Handling of Types [:node]
    --> BLOCK LET LET SB-LOOP::WITH-MINIMAX-VALUE LET SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY
    --> TAGBODY SB-LOOP::LOOP-ACCUMULATE-MINIMAX-VALUE PROGN SETQ
    ==>
      (THE REAL
           (LOOP FOR J ON UPPER-HALF
                 FOR PROD = (* (CAR J) I)
                 WHEN (> UPPER-LIMIT PROD) ...))


Compilation failed.
```

It seems that the compiler assumed that the inner loop returns `Nil` (but it only returns integers; I tested this substituting `collect` for `maximize`). The SBCL Manual goes on and on about type handling, but doesn't explain how to turn this pesky check off. And alas, I couldn't even figure out whether this is a bug or a feature. Well, how do I get this to work?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: It will return `NIL` if the `WHEN` condition is never met.

Comment: What do you mean by "imputes type to closure"? There are no closures here.

Comment: It's just a warning, it shouldn't halt compilation.

Comment: Why are you using `FOR j ON` and `(car j)` instead of `FOR j IN` and `j`?

Comment: You can add something like `FINALLY return 0` to provide a default return value.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that, it's just doing static analysis.

Comment: Re `for j on`, the `j` is used to shorten the `upper-half` list whenever the inner loop returns. This is done by the `prog1` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the inner loop and define another function, as follows:

```
(defun foo (upper-half upper-limit i)
  (loop 
     for j on upper-half
     for prod = (* (car j) i)
     when (> upper-limit prod)
     return (prog1 prod (setf upper-half j))))
```

Its behaviour is different than before, since side-effects are only local. For example, `upper-half` is a local variable whereas in the original code it was a free variable in the copied expression. *This is however not important for type analysis*.

After compilation the function will have the following type (as shown by `describe`):

```
(FUNCTION (T T T) (VALUES (OR NULL SINGLE-FLOAT DOUBLE-FLOAT RATIONAL) &OPTIONAL))
```

---

**Remark** `(values t1 ... tn &optional)` is a way to be explicit about the number of return values of a function (e.g. it must return exactly *n* types). See [`VALUES`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_values.htm):

> [The `&optional` and `&rest` markers] indicate the parameter list of a function that, when given to `multiple-value-call` along with the values, would correctly receive those values.

---

In other words, the returned type of `FOO` is either `NULL` or `REAL`, given that `REAL` above is expanded in terms of its possible subtypes.

The `NULL` type originates from the `NIL` value that can happen when the `loop`   terminates normally.

Now, you don't want to have a `NULL` type in the type union for the resulting type. In other words, you want the loop to never terminate normally. That is easily achieved by signaling an error at the end of the loop:

```
(defun bar (upper-half upper-limit i)
  (loop 
     for j on upper-half
     for prod = (* (car j) i)
     when (> upper-limit prod)
     return (prog1 prod (setf upper-half j))
     finally (error "Impossible")))
```

In the modified function, the normal execution path of the loop eventually reaches a call to `error`, whose return type is `NIL` (a.k.a. the bottom type): it never successfully returns any value. The `NIL` types represents an empty domain and is, as one would expect, a neutral element for the type union.
The inferred type is thus `(OR NIL REAL)`, which is simply `REAL`, the type shown when describing the modified function:

```
(FUNCTION (T T T) (VALUES REAL &OPTIONAL))
```

Answer (score 2):

SBCL does a bit more of static type checking than some other implementations (which is one of the reasons that its compiler is significantly slower than, say, CCL's).  The `maximize` needs the return value of your inner loop to be a `real`, but if the `when` condition is never met, it may return `nil`, which is not a `real`.  It doesn't know (cannot prove) that the input you actually give it never reaches this case, which, if you think about it, would be quite a feat for a general purpose compiler.

Other implementations might not check this.  Even on SBCL, it is just a warning, however, so if you insist on doing it this way, you can ignore it, it still compiles.

You could wrap your inner loop in an `(or … 0)` to satisfy the compiler.  Maybe you can also decrease the `safety` optimization knob to skip this check, but this may have other effects, too.